# При экспорте модели в unity, с некоторых ракурсов пропадают грани

Tags: unity3d

При просмотре модели, обнаружил, что с определенных ракурсов грани становятся прозрачными (или исчезают)

В **Unity**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В **Maya**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если смотреть сзади, то грань есть, а с этого ракурса ее нет, как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с нормалями в модели. Есть два варианта, первый исправить нормали в 3D редакторе( в данном случае Maya), возможно дело в экспорте из редактора.  Посмотрите документацию по импорту из Maya([инструкция](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectMaya.html)). Вы нигде не написали в каком формате выгружаете модель из редактора.

Второй способ выгрузите файл как fbx и забросьте его в проект. Теперь в редакторе Unity ищем файл модели в проекте. Выбираем его и в инспекторе изменяем настройки импорта. Поиграйтесь с группой параметров `Normals & Tangents`. Можно заставить Unity расчитать нормали по встроенному алгоритму, не могу гарантировать что это поможет, но иногда этого достаточно.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже на проблему с ориентацией полигонов.

Как известно, ориентация полигона задается порядком его вершин, условно, "по часовой" или "против часовой стрелки". Например вершины могут быть перечислены как 0-1-2 или 0-2-1 и соответственно полигон будет "смотреть в разные стороны".

Попробуйте или перевернуть их в Майе, или включить рендер двухсторонних полиогнов в Юнити.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, но не могли бы вы подсказать, как сделать рендер двусторонних полигонов? Почитал в интернете, написано, что с помощью двусторонних материалов, но такой опции у меня нет(или я ее не нашел)

Comment: @Артем к сожалению ни с Юнити, ни с Майа не знаком. Ответ дан из общих соображений.

Answer (score 0):

- Нужно извлечь текстуры и материалы вашей модели.

  1 Выбрать вашу модель в окне Project

  2. В окне Inspector перейти на вкладку Materials
  3. Создать папку и извлечь в нее текстуры вашей модели (Extract Textures)
  4. То же самое проделать с материалами модели (Extract Materials)
  5. Выбрать вашу модель в окне сцены и раскрыть его на компоненты
  6. Выбираем каждый компонет модели и в окне Inspector в разделе Shaders изменяем параметр с "Standart" на "Legasy Shaders/Deffuse
     Detail"
  7. Наслаждаемся результатом.

[Источник ответа](https://youtu.be/m3ufW7Q3Tr8)

Answer (score 0):

у меня была похожая ситуация,переносила fbx модель из Cinema 4d в юнити и моделька выворачивалась наизнанку (часть граней становилась прозрачными или пропадала),оказалось были проблемы с нормалями и их просто нужно было инвертировать в синьке